# Document.ready not working on my login page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

So, I have this login page (see code below) and `Document.ready` not working. Is the problem in the script? Could there be something in my code that would make the `document.ready` not work correctly?

I tried to check via the alert messages in my javascript, but they never get hit.

```
@model OpenRoad.Web.Areas.Account.Models.LogOnModel
@using Combres.Mvc
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<title>@string.Format("{0} - {1}", OpenRoad.Web.ApplicationSettings.Title, "Logon")</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/images/favicon.ico" />

@Html.CombresLink("siteCss")
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/App_Themes/" +       OpenRoad.Web.ApplicationSettings.Theme + "/styles.css")" />    
 </head>
 <body class="login">

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Log On";
}
@section scripts {
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('test');
        mixpanel.track("View Logon");
        if ($(".validation-summary-errors")[0]) {
            alert('Found with Length');
        };
    });
 }   
</script>
```

Comment: i dont see jquery included.

Comment: Have you loaded jquery library?

Comment: Is this page using your `_Layout.cshtml` page as the layout? If you view the source of your login page, is the jQuery file up in the full `<head>` tag?

Comment: Just tested out my answer locally and what I suggested is not the problem so I deleted the answer.

Comment: actually that is the issue. I realized this page does not have it loaded because itt doesnt use the same layout. how would i add it to this html?

Comment: On your page where you're setting the `ViewBag.Title` I think you just add `Layout = "_Layout.cshtml"`

Comment: im not trying to use the same layout actually.

Comment: Then you need to add a reference to jQuery directly to the page or define a new layout that contains a reference to jQuery and add that as the layout for the page.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your _Layout.cshtml has this:

```
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

change @section scripts to @section Scripts